# ExecuteCommand returns -1 yet does update record

Tags: c#, sql

This is my update statement built like so:

```
StringBuilder queryUpdate = new StringBuilder();
queryUpdate.AppendFormat("UPDATE TPMdailydata SET FISBTranIntvairmet={0},FISBTranIntvmetr={1},FISBTranIntvnexradnational = {2} ", svd.Data[1].SecPerUpdate.ToString("0.0"), svd.Data[2].SecPerUpdate.ToString("0.0"), svd.Data[3].SecPerUpdate.ToString("0.0"));
queryUpdate.AppendFormat(",FISBTranIntvnexradregional = {0},FISBTranIntvnotam = {1},FISBTranIntvoutage = {2} ", svd.Data[4].SecPerUpdate.ToString("0.0"), svd.Data[5].SecPerUpdate.ToString("0.0"), svd.Data[7].SecPerUpdate.ToString("0.0"));
queryUpdate.AppendFormat(",FISBTranIntvpirep = {0},FISBTranIntvsigmet = {1},FISBTranIntvSUA = {2} ", svd.Data[8].SecPerUpdate.ToString("0.0"), svd.Data[9].SecPerUpdate.ToString("0.0"), svd.Data[10].SecPerUpdate.ToString("0.0"));
queryUpdate.AppendFormat(",FISBTranIntvTAF = {0},FISBTranIntvTISB = {1},FISBTranIntvwind = {2}, AirportID = '{3}' ", svd.Data[11].SecPerUpdate.ToString("0.0"), svd.Data[12].SecPerUpdate.ToString("0.0"), svd.Data[13].SecPerUpdate.ToString("0.0"), des);
queryUpdate.AppendFormat("where SVID = {0} and reportdate = '{Z}' ", (int)svd.ID, rptdate.ToShortDateString());
queryUpdate.AppendFormat("and siteID = '{0}'", siteID);
string cmd = queryUpdate.ToString();
```

Executed by:

```
rowsreturned = this.dba.ExecuteCommand(cmd);
```

Wrote out to Console like so:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("cmd-{0}",cmd)); //+ "and siteID = '{0}'",siteID
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Number of rows updated: {0} UPDATE FISB Data: report date {1} svid {2} ", rowsreturned, rptdate, svd.ID));
```

results as follows:

> cmd-UPDATE TPMdailydata SET FISBTranIntvairmet=124.8,FISBTranIntvmetr=252.0,FISBTranIntvnexradnational = 905.4 ,FISBTranIntvnexradregional = 150.6,FISBTranIntvnotam = 248.5,FISBTranIntvoutage = 0.0 ,FISBTranIntvpirep = 494.8,FISBTranIntvsigmet = 123.8,FISBTranIntvSUA = 551.8 ,FISBTranIntvTAF = 553.7,FISBTranIntvTISB = 13.3,FISBTranIntvwind = 554.1, AirportID = 'ZDC' where SVID = 158 and reportdate = '6/20/2011' and siteID = 'DEV'
>   Number of rows updated: -1 UPDATE FISB Data: report date 6/20/2011 12:00:00 AM svid 158

The update definitely works but I was expecting a return value for the number of rows updated.  I get -1.  I thinking this is bad.  I can't seem to find any info on what the -1 means.
Help anyone?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: This has nothing to do with LINQ.

Comment: True statement.  I am not using LINQ but SQL directly

Answer (score 1):

You need to parameterize you code and add the parameters to the string rather than have people try to navigate the spaghetti mess above. Even if you don't want to do this for maintainability, you will remove the chance of SQL injection.

As for your -1, I am not sure why. There are plenty of things you could have set that accomplish this. What I would try is get away from LINQ, as there is no reason to run this query through the LINQ objects. Here is a pattern that invokes the SQL command directly rather than through the layers of implicit FUD:

```
        string connString = "{Connection string here}";
        string sql = "{SQL Query Here}";

        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                int numRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

ADDED: To try the above methodology, without creating the SQL Connection, you change this:

```
rowsreturned = this.dba.ExecuteCommand(cmd);
```

to this

```
        SqlConnection conn = (SqlConnection) dba.Connection;
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryUpdate, conn))
        {
            rowsreturned = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

This pulls off the context you already have and you can see if rowsReturned still presents an issue. If so, check the command string and consider running it directly in SQL Studio.

Comment: Bravo Gregory, I was also thinking that a plain ExecuteNonQuery with a SqlCommand would work better in this case :)

Comment: sorry i cant figure out how to input my code like you just did.  It is not written poorly just not inserted correctly...back to the point.  I am using ExecuteCommand to execute the SQL statement directly on the SQL 2008 R2 db not through LINQ but as stated in the msdn info page ..Executes SQL commands directly on the database... thanks

Comment: The code is a bit of a mess on setting up the query, which leads to the potential of a serious injection problem. It is using the DB Context to Execute, which means you are dragging along a lot of LINQ (the statement "when all you have is a hammer, all you see is nails" comes to mind). The problem domain does not require everything through LINQ. As for a solution to getting to what I have, I will post another option.

Comment: I am required to use LINQ in the program.  LINQ has issues that will not let my UPDATE run smoothly.  I did run it in SQL Studio and it runs corectly just like the program does..preforms an update. say 1 row affected.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes databases have options which do not send the amount of records updated.

For example, with SQL Server if this is done in the Stored Procedure:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

Then the records effected will always return -1.

There is probably some option like this either with the database or the provider that is preventing the amount of records returned.

Comment: I am not using a stored procedure.  My statements are as stated above.  I will look more into the db options on the server side. thanks

Comment: What's this.dba?  What database are you using?

Comment: dba is my LINQ datacontext connection. Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Maybe the linq gerenated sql is setting this option on (NOCOUNT)?  I beleive behind the scenes the linq call will generate some SQL to be executed against the database, maybe there is a linq option to allow this to be returned?  Sorry, not a linq expert.  But you should be able to capture the sql by doing a SQL Trace to see what linq is sending into SQL Server.